# Can I override the contents of entry_points.txt in a Python-package?

Tags: python

Python packages can contain a file named `entry_points.txt` (example: `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keystone-21.0.0-py3.9.egg-info/entry_points.txt`)

Does python have an interface that lets me override this file's contents without editing the file directly?

Comment: The entry point data is used to generate scripts when a package is being installed. Please add more information about what you want to achieve. Why do you care about the entry point of an installed package?

Comment: In short: My problem is solved by manually adding an entry point, and I don't want it to be reverted when the package is upgraded at one point. (We can use puppet for this, but that would throw away other desired changes too)

The reason why I want to do this;
I want to set up multiple identity providers in OpenStack Keystone for federation purposes. The endpoints that are called back to are tied to the auth provider -- so if I want multiple providers using SAML2, I need to add a second entry point.

... As far as I can tell, Keystone itself does not provide config options for this.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. After reading it, I think I won't be able to help. A package is "advertinsing" its entry points and I doubt it is OK to change that data. The correct way IMO is to make changes in the software that is reading it. Or maybe to create an "adapter" package.